# Simple Slot Machine code chooses same option (Thompson Sampling)

Tags: python, machine-learning

Trying out this simple Slot Machine Code.

```
import numpy as np

slotConRates = [.02, .013, .013, .015, .018]
# Number of Tries
N = 10000
# Number of Machines
d = len(slotConRates)

# Add 1 if you get a Win in the Array X
X = np.zeros((N,d))
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(d):
    if np.random.rand() < slotConRates[j]:
      X[i][j] = 1

win_reward = np.zeros(d)
loss_reward = np.zeros(d)

# Taking our best Slot Machine through beta distribution and updating it's loss and wins

for i in range(N):
  selected = 0
  MaxRandom = 0
  for j in range(d):
    randomBeta = np.random.beta(win_reward[j] + 1, loss_reward[j] + 1)
    if randomBeta > MaxRandom:
      MaxRandom = randomBeta
      selected = j
      if X[i][selected] == 1:
        win_reward[selected] += 1
      else:
        loss_reward[selected] += 1
# Showing which slot machine is considered the best
nSelected = win_reward + loss_reward 
for i in range(d):
    print('Machine number ' + str(i + 1) + ' was selected ' + str(nSelected[i]) + ' times')
print('Conclusion: Best machine is machine number ' + str(np.argmax(nSelected) + 1))
```

It is always selecting the 1st machine the choice for every iteration though.

```
Machine number 1 was selected 10000.0 times
Machine number 2 was selected 1181.0 times
Machine number 3 was selected 1108.0 times
Machine number 4 was selected 640.0 times
Machine number 5 was selected 1314.0 times
Conclusion: Best machine is machine number 1
```

How should I fix this? The second `for` loop is the issue. Any insights into why this is happening?

Comment: You start each `j`-loop with `MaxRandom = 0` and therefore `randomBeta > MaxRandom` is always `True` for `j == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are doing, but I somehow think that this slight modification (change of indentation of last `if`-`else`-block) might be what you are looking for:

```
...
for i in range(N):
    selected = 0
    MaxRandom = 0
    for j in range(d):
        randomBeta = np.random.beta(win_reward[j] + 1, loss_reward[j] + 1)
        if randomBeta > MaxRandom:
            MaxRandom = randomBeta
            selected = j
    if X[i][selected] == 1:
        win_reward[selected] += 1
    else:
        loss_reward[selected] += 1
...
```

**EDIT**:
Typical result after adjustment:

```
win_reward = array([ 34.,   7.,   3.,  20., 124.])
loss_reward = array([1733.,  656.,  431., 1271., 5721.])
nSelected = array([1767.,  663.,  434., 1291., 5845.])
Machine number 1 was selected 1767.0 times
Machine number 2 was selected 663.0 times
Machine number 3 was selected 434.0 times
Machine number 4 was selected 1291.0 times
Machine number 5 was selected 5845.0 times
Conclusion: Best machine is machine number 5
(Test sum over selections: 10000.0)
```

---

Complete listing that I have used:

```
import numpy as np

slotConRates = [.02, .013, .013, .015, .018]
N = 10000
d = len(slotConRates)

X = np.zeros((N,d))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(d):
        if np.random.rand() < slotConRates[j]:
            X[i][j] = 1

win_reward = np.zeros(d)
loss_reward = np.zeros(d)

for i in range(N):
    selected = 0
    MaxRandom = 0
    for j in range(d):
        randomBeta = np.random.beta(win_reward[j] + 1, loss_reward[j] + 1)
        if randomBeta > MaxRandom:
            MaxRandom = randomBeta
            selected = j
    if X[i][selected] == 1:
        win_reward[selected] += 1
    else:
        loss_reward[selected] += 1

nSelected = win_reward + loss_reward 
print(f'{win_reward = }')
print(f'{loss_reward = }')
print(f'{nSelected = }')
for i in range(d):
    print(f'Machine number {i + 1} was selected {nSelected[i]} times')
print(f'Conclusion: Best machine is machine number {np.argmax(nSelected) + 1}')
print(f'(Test sum over selections: {nSelected.sum()})')
```

Comment: No. That is not it. This is a simple demo for Thompson Sampling..used in Artificial Intelligence. The question is the whole program. You can simply copy it and run it to check.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Okay, then see my comment above: `10000` is inevitable for `nSelected[0]`.

Comment: @AbhishekRai In addition: If the indenation of the `if`-`else`-block is correct, then why the line `selected = j` and not simply use just `j`?

Comment: @AbhishekRai One last comment: If you look [here](https://www.aionlinecourse.com/tutorial/machine-learning/thompson-sampling-intuition), somewhere after the middle, you'll find code that is pretty similiar to yours (starts with `# Implementing Thompson Sampling`). And the indentation of the `if`-`else`-block that counts the rewards is pretty much in line with my suggestion.

Comment: I tried it yesterday...it again gave a wrong count for Machine number 1(greater than N). You can copy the code and indent it the way you want it. Then maybe you will see why it is not working.

Comment: @AbhishekRai I did that already, see my edit of the answer: I don't get this effect?

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: @AbhishekRai Sure, see the edit (results + code I have used)

Comment: That was it...Don't know why it didn't work yesterday.